# Order of elements of a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Assume that G is an abelian group, and a∈G.

(a) Assume that |a|=r and that m|r, say r=mt. Prove that $|a^t|$=m.

Proof:Assume a∈G and |a|=r and m|r, say r=mt.

Assume $|a^t|$=k

Since $a^r=(a^t)^m$=e.  So r=tm is the smallest positive interger such that $(a^t)^m$=e

Then m|k. But $|a^t|$=k, so k|m. Thus, k=m.

Therefore, $|a^t|$=m

(b) Assume that G/$<a>$ has an element $<a>$d of order m. Let |d|=k. Prove that m|k and if k=ms, then $|d^s|$=m.

Proof: Assume that G/$<a>$ has an element $<a>$d of order m. Let |d|=k.

Then $(<a>d)^m$=$<a>d^m$=$<a>e$=$<a>$. Then m is the smallest positive integer such that $d^m$=e. Then m|k.

And if k=ms, then |$d^s$|=m by part (a)

Comment: I am doing it correct?

Comment: Without checking too much it looks fine....but you **really** should by now learn how to type mathematics in this site as yourposts are very hard to understand.

Comment: @NadiaC: [This meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/39599) has some helpful information about using MathJax on this site.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thanks, that helps.